# Django renaming class casued AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

How can I solve this issue, I renamed a through Model class and now getting the following error when trying to migrate:

```
(django_env) UKC02TQH6UHV22:pcc_django rki23$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, microblog, project_portal, sessions, url_tree
Running migrations:
  Applying project_portal.0012_auto_20200205_1241...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/rki23/opt/anaconda3/envs/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/Users/rki23/opt/anaconda3/envs/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/rki23/opt/anaconda3/envs/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/rki23/opt/anaconda3/envs/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/rki23/opt/anaconda3/envs/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rki23/opt/anaconda3/envs/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/Users/rki23/opt/anaconda3/envs/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/rki23/opt/anaconda3/envs/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/rki23/opt/anaconda3/envs/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/rki23/opt/anaconda3/envs/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/rki23/opt/anaconda3/envs/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 249, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/Users/rki23/opt/anaconda3/envs/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 524, in alter_field
    not new_field.remote_field.through._meta.auto_created):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
(django_env) UKC02TQH6UHV22:pcc_django rki23$
```

What do I need to do to fix this please?

THis is the migration file that is causing the issue. The name change was for a many to many field.

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.5 on 2020-02-05 12:41

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('project_portal', '0011_auto_20200127_0953'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RenameModel(
            old_name='CategorySatisfied',
            new_name='TaskComplete',
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='updatecategory',
            name='projects',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, related_name='task_complete', through='project_portal.CategorySatisfied', to='project_portal.Project'),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: You need to show migration code first. `new_field.remote_field.through` is looks like a string (through table name) but not a table itself (I guess it's M2M through table, right?).

Comment: Hi, you are correct, I've just updated my post to include the migration file.

Comment: check this out <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393393/django-makemigrations-attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-meta>

Comment: Doesn't seem that relavent to my issue, he has an error in his model in that he was setting a variable to a model that did not exist and correcting the name of the through model can fix it. This is not the case as far as I can see with mine, as it is the Through model that I wanted to change the name for and that name only appears in two other places both of which were changed.